# How to show/hide google mapview programatically?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

My project has 2 fragment (2 tabs), contain  2 MapView on each. I want to show/hide google mapview programatically. How to do that?
Below is my code.

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
```

---

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, container, false);


        mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        mMapView1 = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView1);
        mMapView1.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView1.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

My requirement is when significance is home i want to show the first google map otherwise hide it and when significance is work i want to show the second google map otherwise hide it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ingredObject = subArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject defObject = ingredObject.getJSONObject("place");
                        final String name = defObject.getString("name");
                        final String significance = ingredObject.getString("significance");
                        final String latitude = ingredObject.getString("latitude");
                        final String longitude = ingredObject.getString("longitude");


                        if (significance.equals("home")) {

                            mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                                    googleMap = mMap;

                                    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                                            .getString(R.string.style_json)));

                                    if (!success) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
                                    }
                                    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                                    LatLng home = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                                    List<Address> addresses = null;
                                    try {
                                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude), 1);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                    Marker marker3 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title(significance).snippet(getString(R.string.home_location)));
                                    marker3.showInfoWindow();

                                    // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(home).zoom(17).build();
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (significance.equals("work")) {
                            mMapView1.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                                    googleMap = mMap;

                                    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
                                            .getString(R.string.style_json)));

                                    if (!success) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
                                    }
                                    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map

                                    LatLng home = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                                    List<Address> addresses = null;
                                    try {
                                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude), 1);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                    Marker marker4 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title(name).snippet(getString(R.string.work_location)));
                                    marker4.showInfoWindow();

                                    // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(home).zoom(17).build();
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I believe it would be better if you use only one `MapView` and update the information you display.. Other than that if you want to keep using two you should consider them as a `View` and change the visibility based on which one you want to display

Answer (score 1):

In java code

> layout_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show LinearLayout
>
> layout_2.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide LinearLayout

same for layout_1

In xml code

```
 <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
yourMapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);// to hide
```

and to show

```
yourMapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// TO SHOW
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 mMapView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //To INVISIBLE
```